# On Button Click code under Switch Button is not Working

Tags: android, kotlin

On `Button` Click, I want to get data on second `activity` from edit text only if the Switch button is `ON` but unable to do this anyone can help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val nextButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nextButton)
        nextButton.setOnClickListener {
            nextPage()
        }
    }
    private fun nextPage(){
        val etName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
        val etEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email)
        val etPhone = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phone)
        val etPassPort = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)
        var passport = ""
        if (etPassPort.isChecked) { passport = etPassPort.text.toString()  }
        val mName = etName.text.toString()
        val mEmail = etEmail.text.toString()
        val mPhone = etPhone.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ViewActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Name", mName)
        intent.putExtra("Email", mEmail)
        intent.putExtra("Phone", mPhone)
        intent.putExtra("CHECKBOX", passport)
        val mySwitch = findViewById<SwitchCompat>(R.id.mySwitch)
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
                val et = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sponsorName)
                val mEt = et.text.toString()
                intent.putExtra("SPONSOR", mEt)
        }
    }
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.kt**

```
class ViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view)

        val intent =  intent
        val mName = intent.getStringExtra("Name")
        val mEmail = intent.getStringExtra("Email")
        val mPhone = intent.getStringExtra("Phone")
        val checkbox = intent.getStringExtra("CHECKBOX")
        val mEt = intent.getStringExtra("SPONSOR")

        //textview
        val resultTv = findViewById<View>(R.id.resultTV) as TextView
        //setText
        resultTv.text = mName+"\n"+mEmail+"\n"+mPhone+"\n"+checkbox+"\n"+mEt

    }

}
```

Switch button code is working fine when i release it from the Button Click. Under the Button Click only null value is showing in Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue of Switch Button by declaring it globally here is my working code.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var sponsor : Boolean = false
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val mySwitch = findViewById<SwitchCompat>(R.id.mySwitch)
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            sponsor = true
        }
    }

    val nextButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nextButton)
    nextButton.setOnClickListener {
        nextPage()
    }
}
private fun nextPage(){
    val etName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
    val etEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email)
    val etPhone = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phone)
    val etPassPort = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)
    var passport = ""
    if (etPassPort.isChecked) { passport = etPassPort.text.toString()  }
    val mName = etName.text.toString()
    val mEmail = etEmail.text.toString()
    val mPhone = etPhone.text.toString()
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ViewActivity::class.java)
    val et = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sponsorName)
    val mEt = et.text.toString()
    intent.putExtra("SPONSOR", mEt)
    intent.putExtra("Name", mName)
    intent.putExtra("Email", mEmail)
    intent.putExtra("Phone", mPhone)
    intent.putExtra("CHECKBOX", passport)
    intent.putExtra("Switch",sponsor.toString())
    startActivity(intent)}}
```

**SecondActivity.kt**

```
class ViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var pdfButton: Button
private var permissionCode = 101
private val STORAGE_CODE: Int = 100
val resultTv = findViewById<View>(R.id.resultTV) as TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view)
    val intent = intent
    val mName = intent.getStringExtra("Name")
    val mEmail = intent.getStringExtra("Email")
    val mPhone = intent.getStringExtra("Phone")
    val checkbox = intent.getStringExtra("CHECKBOX")
    val mEt = intent.getStringExtra("SPONSOR")
    val sponsor1 = intent.getStringExtra("Switch")
    //textview

    //setText
    resultTv.text =
        mName + "\n" + mEmail + "\n" + mPhone + "\n" + checkbox + "\n" + mEt + "\n" + sponsor1

    if (sponsor1 == "true") {

        resultTv.text = mName + "\n" + mEmail + "\n" + mPhone + "\n" + checkbox + "\n" + mEt

    } else {
        resultTv.text = mName + "\n" + mEmail + "\n" + mPhone + "\n" + checkbox

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know where is the problem, first of all you call the buttonCLick, and inside it you call the method nextPage(), if we look closely, this block of code

```
val mySwitch = findViewById<SwitchCompat>(R.id.mySwitch)
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
if (isChecked) {
        val et = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sponsorName)
        val mEt = et.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra("SPONSOR", mEt)
}
```

}

is inside your click button, and by default your switch is not checked, so you pass all data, but `intent.putExtra("SPONSOR", mEt)` is not executed, so when the second activity receive the data is show a null error because `val mEt = intent.getStringExtra("SPONSOR")` is null.
You have two solution, either you write the block of the switch code outside the click button, or in the second activity you check with a conditionif all your data are not null.

Comment: I put block of switch code in second activity but the application is crashing.

Comment: in your second activity try to your this, if( intent.getStringExtra("SPONSOR") != null){
        val mEt = intent.getStringExtra("SPONSOR")}